# Ember not linking related models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, promise

This is a common problem I'm having, so I guess it is something I'm doing wrong.

I have models:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    author: DS.hasMany('author')
});

App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    post: DS.belongsTo('post)
});
```

A single REST call to fetch a post includes the author, so I know that after `store.find('post')` I have all posts and authors in the store.  However, when I render a page with this data (using an `ArrayController`, I notice that the related authors take some time render, although there is only a single request.  Further inspection shows that in the route's `setupController`, the data has all been loaded into the store, but the relationships have not been set.  If I do:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('post');
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        model.forEach(function(post) {
            console.log(post.get('author'));
        });
        controller.set('model', model);
    }
});
```

The console log shows a list of "undefined" as each author.

Only a single request is made to the server and I have checked that the response is valid.  Also, the data is eventually rendered, but for a few seconds `undefined` shown where I have `{{author.name}}` in the template.  It looks like the data is loaded, but the connections are not made until much later.  I can't find anything in the documentation explaining this, and I can't figure out a way to force it to load properly before rendering.  I am already using a `loading` template and I have tried forcing it to load in `model`:

```
model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        posts: this.store.find('post'),
        authors: this.store.find('author')
    });
}
```

But nothing makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with this, since the model is a *promise* ?

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('post');
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        model.then(function(result){
            result.forEach(function(post) {
               console.log(post.get('author.name'));
            });
        });        
        controller.set('model', model);
    }
});
```

and I'm not sure whether this is copy paste typo or not, but worthy to check

```
App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    post: DS.belongsTo('post) // missing the closing quote
});
```